# making Valgrind happy with strdup

Tags: c++, valgrind

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
   string s1 = "String";
   char *s2 = strdup(s1.c_str());
   free(s2);
   return 0;
}
```

Valgrind is reporting the following on the code posted above:

```
==29608== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==29608==    at 0x41F9049: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libc.so.6)
==29608==    by 0x41F8C25: strdup (in /usr/local/lib/libc.so.6)
==29608==    by 0x804D704: main
```

What is Valgrind complaining about? Can I safely ignore this error?

Comment: Did you paste your whole code? I run your piece of code and valgrind is happy with that, no errors detected.

Comment: Works for me as well without any errors

Comment: @George - Fine as in leaking!?